# Como puedo hacer una alerta con sweetalert que se active minutos después de dar click en un boton

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

```
  var Button= document.getElementById('HInit'); 
  var Temp = function(){
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('Submit').disabled=false",30000);
   var i=document.getElementById("hini").value = "<?php
    echo date('H:i')?>";
    swal({
```

title: "¡Se Acabo el Tiempo!",
text: "El tiempo de prueba a finalizado",
type: "info",
timer:30000
});
}

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser algo así:

```
var millisecondsToWait = 2000;
setTimeout(function(){
    Swal.fire("El tiempo se ha agotado",
                       "Su tiempo se agotó!",
                       "success");
}, millisecondsToWait);
```

la variable millisecondsToWait son los milisegundos que esperara para correr el código en la function dentro de setTimeout, en mi caso puse 2000 pero tú usa lo que necesites.
Espero que te funcione!